# Hovering over featured moves the questions down a bit

Tags: bug, design, meta, google-chrome, bountied-tab

When I hover over featured tab, both on the front page and in questions, the questions move down by one pixel. Here's a small screen capture demonstrating the issue:

> [image]

I see it in Chrome 34 and Opera 20, but I don't see it on IE11 or Firefox 28.

Comment: Norepro in Chrome 34.0.1847.116m, Win7

Comment: Ah good, I wanted to report this but I have dev channel Chrome and was too lazy to confirm it did indeed happen in stable.

Comment: [Reproduced on Chrome Version 34.0.1847.131 m](http://i.stack.imgur.com/JXe1j.gif)...

Comment: Nooooo. I like that *dancing animation*.

Comment: [meta-tag:status-norepro] Chrome 38.0.2125.111 m *and* 38.0.2125.122 m.

Comment: [status-norepro] on Safari 7.1, Mac.

Comment: @Sha sure it is bug still?

Comment: @nicael yes, exact same behavior as described in the report. That said, in IE it's fine, only Chrome is misbehaving.

Comment: Switch to IE, ditch Chrome @ShadowWizard

Comment: I can't repro on any browser anymore.

Comment: Hmm... maybe it's somehow related to [this bug](http://superuser.com/questions/803601/text-size-suddenly-got-bigger-on-all-sites-on-google-chrome)? I will check on other machines.